# How to add capabilities for non logged-in users (guest) in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to give certain capabilities to my guest via https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap without requiring them to register or log in. How is this possible?